# Import Activity locking file before import starts

Tags: dataextensions, data, automationstudio, import, ftp

I have created an automation that has an Import Activity from my SFTP. What we have noticed is that the automation seems to have been writing over the file prior to the automation running (it's set to run at 5am).

Here are the logs:

> 00:29:37.050     06/17/2018     Worker-0     [sfmc-vrtp-outbound-adapter->v1].sfmc-vrtp-outbound-adapter-v1Flow.stage1.13     INFO Successfully wrote file >'TG_VGS_DATA_20180616.csv' to sftp://MID:****@ftp.s6.exacttarget.com:22/Import
>
> 01:29:40.090     06/17/2018     Worker-0     [sfmc-vrtp-outbound-adapter-v1].sfmc-vrtp-outbound-adapter-v1Flow.stage1.14     INFO Successfully wrote file >'TG_VGS_DATA_20180616.csv' to sftp://MID:****@ftp.s6.exacttarget.com:22/Import
>
> 02:29:44.925     06/17/2018     Worker-0     [sfmc-vrtp-outbound-adapter->v1].sfmc-vrtp-outbound-adapter-v1Flow.stage1.15     INFO Successfully wrote file >'TG_VGS_DATA_20180616.csv' to sftp://MID:****@ftp.s6.exacttarget.com:22/Import
>
> 03:29:47.132     06/17/2018     Worker-0     [sfmc-vrtp-outbound-adapter->v1].sfmc-vrtp-outbound-adapter-v1Flow.stage1.16     INFO Successfully wrote file >'TG_VGS_DATA_20180617.csv' to sftp://MID:****@ftp.s6.exacttarget.com:22/Import

Is it possible that the SFMC process had locked the file or kept it open preventing a update?

If it was a data issue, the file would have had the header row, but no data. With this problem, the file was completely blank.